# JS Settype like PHP

Tags: javascript

I have variable on my JS `qty`, the type is string.
How to change it into `integer or float`?

in PHP we have settype, try the same way with JS. it not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var qtyInt = parseInt(qty);
var qtyFloat = parseFloat(qty);
```

Comment: beware that passing non-numeric values into these functions will give you a result of `NaN` (Not a Number). This can then result in errors later in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Convert string to float: var myFloat = parseFloat('77.3');    // 77.3

Convert string to integer: var myInt = parseInt('14');    // 14